# Getting error in linq to entity

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Getting three errors:

1. cannot convert from 'employer' to 'JobPortalModel.employer'
2. The best overloaded method match for 
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet.AddObject
   (JobPortalModel.employer)' has some invalid arguments
3. 'employer' does not contain a definition for 'c_type' and no
   extension method
   'c_type' accepting a first argument of type 'employer' could be
   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   using JobPortalModel;

   public partial class Reg_employer : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       JobPortalEntities je1= new JobPortalEntities();
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           acctyp.Text = Session["Account"].ToString();

       }
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string Type = acctyp.Text;
           string Name = txtname.Text;
           string Email = txtmail.Text;
           string Password = txtpass.Text;
           string RePassword = txtrepass.Text;
           string Details = txtdtls.Text;
           string Website = txtwbst.Text;
           string Image=fplg.FileName;
           string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Image).ToLower();
           if (ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".bmp" || ext == ".jpg")
           {
               string sp = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\logo//" + Image;
               fplg.SaveAs(sp);
               string ps = "~/logo/" + Image;
               employer e2=new employer();
                   e2.c_type = Type;
                   e2.c_name = Name;
                   e2.c_mail = Email;
                   e2.c_pass = Password;
                   e2.c_repass = RePassword;
                   e2.c_details = Details;
                   e2.c_website = Website;
                   e2.c_img = ps;
                   je1.employer.AddObject(e2);
                   je1.SaveChanges();

           }

           Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

       }

       private string conv(string p)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please Help/.. I am new in .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an employer class somewhere, which is conflicting with JobPortalModel.employer. You can do like this:

```
//employer e2=new employer();
JobPortalModel.employer e2=new JobPortalModel.employer();
```

You need to be careful about naming variables.
Change this:

```
string Type = acctyp.Text;
... ... ...
string Image=fplg.FileName;
```

To this:

```
string type = acctyp.Text;
... ... ...
string image=fplg.FileName;
```

And change this:

```
string sp = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\logo//" + Image;
                ... ... ...
                string ps = "~/logo/" + Image;
                ... ... ...
                    e2.c_type = Type;
```

To this:

```
string sp = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\logo//" + image;
                ... ... ...
                string ps = "~/logo/" + image;
                ... ... ...
                    e2.c_type = type;
```

You can find Microsoft's naming guideline [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Sayantan Das - unlike other forums we prefer accepting and/or upvoting an answer if it helps. Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/231966).

Comment: I cant vote up ur answer.. sorry sir.. Its saying I need some reputation.